# NHibernate Desktop App : should it use multiple sessions?

Tags: database, nhibernate, session

Should a NHibernate desktop app use a SessionFactory and multiple sessions ? Does the **One session per transaction** rule apply only to web applications  ?

Regards,
MadSeb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, an NHibernate desktop application should typically use multiple sessions.

In a two-tier scenario, you'll use a session per logical "session of interaction," such as a given "view" or "screen." Here you can maintain the session longer than you could in a web application, and reap the full benefit of lazy-loading, but at some point you want the user to "save" or "cancel" and move on to something else, and this is often a good place to end the session.

Using a single session throughout the application can cause a lot of stuff to be cached, and the client-side data may become stale or you could run into concurrency problems.

Furthermore, once a session encounters an exception, it is no longer valid and you'll have to abandon/reset whatever you were doing. If that is one form, it isn't a big deal, but if you have lots of objects throughout your application referencing the same session, they'll all be in a compromised state.

Comment: what's the proper proceedure for cleaning up the Session after an exception?

Comment: @Tom Per the NH documentation, `If the ISession throws an exception you should immediately rollback the transaction, call Session.Close() and discard the ISession instance.`

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  A session should be as short lived as possible, since it is seen as a unit-of-work.

Therefore, I would create a session per 'use case'.  (A use-case can span multiple forms).